# Change border color of div inside of another div div

Tags: css, vue.js

I got this Vue component (https://www.vue2editor.com):

```
<vue-editor id="description" name="description"
:class="{'uk-form-danger': errors.has('description') }"
v-model="description"
:editorToolbar="customToolbar" v-validate="'required'">
</vue-editor>
```

which renders the following HTML markup:

```
<div class="quillWrapper" name="description" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
    <div class="ql-toolbar ql-snow"><span class="ql-formats"></span></div>
    <div id="description" class="ql-container ql-snow">
        <div class="ql-editor ql-blank" data-gramm="false" contenteditable="true"><p><br></p></div>
        <div class="ql-clipboard" contenteditable="true" tabindex="-1"></div>
        <div class="ql-tooltip ql-hidden"><a class="ql-preview" target="_blank" href="about:blank"></a>
            <input
                type="text" data-formula="e=mc^2" data-link="https://quilljs.com" data-video="Embed URL">
            <a
                class="ql-action"></a><a class="ql-remove"></a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I would like to add the class `uk-form-danger` (compare https://getuikit.com/docs/form#states-modifiers) to the parent div.

As you can see, I am doing this by binding the class on error.

Well. The problem is: The `uk-form-danger` class does not add a red border color to the text editor.

These is the css of `.ql-toolbar.ql-snow`:

```
.ql-toolbar.ql-snow {
border: 1px solid #ccc;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
padding: 8px;
```

This is the css of uk-form-danger:

```
 *
 * Error
 */
.uk-form-danger,
.uk-form-danger:focus {
  color: #f0506e;
  border-color: #f0506e;
}
```

I could edit the css by adding a custom scss to my project - but what should I add there?

Thanks for your support :-)

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is related to *CSS specificity* — `.ql-toolbar.ql-snow` is a more "powerful" selector than just the `.uk-form-danger` class.

The quickest fix for your custom SCSS would be to add the `!important;` attribute to the error styles, so your custom code might look like this:

```
.uk-form-danger {
  border-color: #f0506e !important;
}
```